# Cannot reach docker (for windows) containers on localhost port mapping when pulse vpn is active

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have 2 docker containers running IIS and SQL DB on **Docker for Windows**. I can reach these on their internal ip addresses either on 172.27.*.* or via mapped ports i.e. localhost:8000 as per the mapping contained in the docker compose file.

When my vpn client connects, I can no longer reach the containers on the localhost mapping. As soon as I suspend the vpn connection, the access is restored. The VPN client is pulse VPN. Split tunnelling is enabled. When the VPN is connected I can continue to access local network resources, such as my NAS on a 192.168.0.x subnet.

I tried shifting the default subnet to 192.168.x.x in with the following appended to docker-compose file

```
networks:
  default:
    driver: nat
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet:  192.168.200.1/16
```

With this, I get a container ip address like so

```
"Gateway": "192.168.0.1",
"IPAddress": "192.168.55.249"
```

Again without VPN I reach the container web server on the direct ip and via the localhost:8000 mapping. With the VPN up, I loose the connection via localhost:8000 but can still reach it via 192.168.55.249

If I change the order - stop the containers with docker-compose down, then connect the vpn, then bring up the containers then I get the same result, the localhost mapping stops working, the direct IP continues to work.

Is there a way to fix the localhost mapping so that it continues to work when the VPN is connected?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while but maybe someone else has the problem....

You have to configure Pulse secure to allow access to local subnets.

https://docs.pulsesecure.net/WebHelp/PCS/8.3R1/Home.htm#PCS/PCS_AdminGuide_8.3/Defining_the_Route_Precedence.htm

Same Problem is described here:
https://community.pulsesecure.net/t5/Pulse-Connect-Secure/Pulse-vs-Docker/td-p/15514